# How do you estimate the scale parameter for a random parameter logit using mlogit in R

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate a random parameter logit/mixed logit model using the `mlogit` package in R. My model looks like this,

```
wlsq.obese_conf.model <- mlogit(formula = choice ~ noadveff + tab + infreq_1 + weightloss + I(weightloss^2) + optout + cost| -1 | 0,
                            data = mlogit.obese_conf,
                            rpar = c(noadveff = 'n', tab = 'n', infreq_1 = 'n', weightloss = 'n', optout1 = "n"),
                            R = 100,
                            halton = NA,
                            print.level = 0,
                            panel = TRUE,
                            estimate = TRUE,
                            weights = weighting.x
)
```

I am running the same model on a different subsample, and need to compare the scale parameters between the two subsamples. However, I have not been able to identify a method for extracting the parameter - do anyone know how I can do this in `mlogit`?

Comment: Have you tried `coef(wlsq.obese_conf.model)` and `summary(wlsq.obese_conf.model`? (Or are the "scale parameters" something different?)

Comment: The scale parameters are something different :)

Comment: So do you know any method to explore these parameters directly or indirectly (and you just don't know how to extract them) or are they completely hidden and you just know that they must have been calculated by `mlogit`?

Comment: Not exactly, i do not know how to calculate them, but I hoped someone inhere could tell me. The supervisor for my thesis tells me that it should be possible to estimate for rpl, so that's why i'm wondering if it hidden somewhere in the package?

Comment: For the econometric questions, [crossvalidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) might be a better platform. Last try from my side: Did you take a look at `str(wlsq.obese_conf.model)`, anything that looks helpful in the output?

Comment: Sadly no. I have already checked all this :)